# How to trace / track user input on touch screen to match image on screen

Tags: javascript, svg, touch-event, touchscreen

So I want to have an image, let's say a square and would want the user to 'trace' the image with their finger, I need to track this and know / understand if the user has done it correctly.

The use case is educational software where users trace shapes to learn how to draw them.

My thinking was an SVG object and then mouse hold events but because SVG has beginning and end points I am not sure if they could then be tracked all the way over the image etc.

Also how? If I have interaction on the SVG is it a matter of if statements and some kind of variance on the line and if user gets to far away from the original line then stop / break?

Sorry if this is explained badly also I couldn't find almost anything so I'm also sorry if this is a duplicate.

Found this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/

And: https://gist.github.com/elidupuis/11325438 / http://bl.ocks.org/elidupuis/11325438

So could maybe cobble something together but yes any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function setMouseCoordinates(event) {
    // contains the size of element having id 'image svg' and its position relative to the viewport, svg width/height equal to image height and width
    var boundary = document.getElementById('<id_of_image_svg>').getBoundingClientRect();
    // sets the x position of the mouse co-ordinate
    auth_mouseX = event.clientX - boundary.left;
    // sets the y position of the mouse co-ordinate
    auth_mouseY = event.clientY - boundary.top;
    return [auth_mouseX, auth_mouseY];

}

// add this in mousedown or respective touch event 
function drawPath(event) {
    var {
        auth_mouseX,
        auth_mouseY
    } = setMouseCoordinates(event);
    // Creates an element with the specified namespace URI and qualified name.
    scribble = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'path');
    // sets the stroke width and color of the drawing drawn by scribble drawing tool
    scribble.style.stroke = 'red';
    // sets the stroke width of the scribble drawing
    scribble.style.strokeWidth = '2';
    scribble.style.fill = 'none';
    scribble.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M' + auth_mouseX + ' ' + auth_mouseY);
}
```

Now you can add this function in the touchdown event and create logic accordingly. You have to check that the user has start or stopped the drawing by a varible and changing its value accordingly.

For evaluation of task whether it is in a given area or not you have to use some shape detection api or AI (You can search on google there are many of them like AWS rekognition and many others I don't remember the name)

Hope it helps anyhow. :)